# How do I send email notifications when pull request status approved or rejected in azure-devops

Tags: azure-devops

when a submission PR is approved or rejected ,we want to send out an email notification that has the relevant information

Answer (score 0):

> How do I send email notifications when pull request status approved or rejected in azure-devops

You could create a new subscription for your request.

You could to get the email notifications for the overall status notification for PRs, like:

[image]

Or you want to be notified of every vote and reject, then you can set it like this：

[image]

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled) for some more details.